# Can I upgrade Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise to VS 2017 Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, upgrade

I have VS 2015 Enterprise on my machine. Can I easily upgrade it to 2017 Enterprise? If yes, how? Will the license key for VS 2015 do for VS 2017?

Comment: You can keep both of VS 2015 and VS 2017 on the same computer and the VS 2015 license key should not used to VS 2017, you can have a try and if not works, apply for another education version for VS 2017 like you did before for VS 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You don't upgrade Visual Studio. You can however install side by side (I have machines with multiple versions of VS in active use).

> Will the license key for VS 2015 do for VS 2017?

Assuming you mean a retail key (rather than an MSDN/Visual Studio subscription) then no.

Comment: Thanks Richard. It was an education version key.

Comment: @ Alex Konnen, If Richard's reply was helpful for you and resolve this issue, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours.